# How to describe a Turing Machine that accepts zeros in power of 3?

Tags: graphs, turing-machines

I need to describe by a graph a turing machine that can accept the language:
A = {0^(3^n ) |n≥0} =  { 0 , 000 , 0^9 , 0^27 , ... }.  **zeros in powers of 3**

This here is a turing machine that can accept the language:
A = {0^(2^n ) |n≥0}    If that helps somehow..
[image]

Comment: Mmm.. I tried a lot of things, never got it right :/  I expect a drawing like the one for the power of 2's that I attached

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this as a tip cause this catches pow 3 but also (pow 3)*2 :: 9 and 18
I sadly can't solve it perfectly right now but I'm certain you don't need more than 9 states, hope it helps you solve and I'm interested to see a real solution

Ps for you just a --> 0
[image: Not Solution]

Comment: Could you add textual description to your diagram? How does it work? Why does it work? If it does not, it shouldn't be posted as the answer.

Comment: As I said I wanted to post this as a comment but I can't.      I could only post a solution. As to how it works: well i tried to force it to do a circle of three twice so it would be a 3^n, maybe if ill force it to do 3 circles it will be perfect?  I'm sorry to say I can't explain better than that

Comment: I will hopefully have a full solution in a week or two as me and some friends are working on it